# org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile vulnerability

Tags: log4j, slf4j

We need to migrate to log4j 2.17 if we are using log4j jar, mvn dependency: tree showing only log4j-over-slf4j:jar. so I assume app is safe as it will redirect call to sl4j not to log4j.
Please confirm my app is safe with this jar without any remediation.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SLF4J website, in the [Comments on the log4shell(CVE-2021-44228) vulnerability](https://www.slf4j.org/log4shell.html) they state that:

*If you are using `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` in conjunction with the SLF4J API, you are safe unless the underlying implementation is log4j 2.x.*

So it basically depends on how you're implementing the logs' generation. **Slf4j natively uses logback**. But to be sure, you can check your `pom.xml` and see if log4j is mentioned there.

Comment: Yes,  slf4j using logback in my app. Thank You.